# How to solve DLL load failed:A dynamic link library (DLL) initialisation routine failed. of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

I am using Python 3.7.3 and pip version 20.1 and I installed tensorflow 2.0 using pip. I've successfully installed tensorflow. But when I try to run import tensorflow as tf it shows error as ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialisation routine failed.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

I've gone through the link provided along with the error but couldn't find this particular type of error. If Anyone has faced this typeof error and solved it please help me solve too.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialisation routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Aayush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialisation routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Answer (score 1):

New version of tensorflow (for example I am using tensorflow v2.2) windows installation needs `Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable`

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#install_visual_c_build_tools_2019

After you have install `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019` from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ under the section `Other Tools and Frameworks`, you will be able to run it.